# crontab add a wait time between move, copy, unzip, move

Tags: linux, cron

How to add a wait time between crontab jobs commands?

There may be other errors in this code. But the main goal is at 10pm to execute one line, wait for the previous to complete, then move to the next, etc...

```
crontab -e

#* 22 * * * ##At 10pm, do the following in order waiting for each to complete before moving on.


mv /home/$USER/isengard /home/$USER/middleearth/mirkwood
wait
cp -r -p /home/$USER/middleearth/mirkwood /home/$USER/middleearth/shire/
wait
mv /home/$USER/middleearth/mirkwood /home/$USER/middleearth/rohan/
wait
gunzip -r /home/$USER/middleearth/rohan/
wait
mv /home/$USER/middleearth/rohan /home/$USER/middleearth/gondor/
```

Comment: Just make them a single command line?  `* 22 * * * mv blah blah ; cp blah blah ; mv blah blah ; gunzip blah blah ; etc`.  If you want a delay between, then `mv blah blah ; sleep 1m ; cp blah blah...`

Comment: Or create a script with these commands, and have crontab execute the script.

Comment: All those operations are atomic, so unless you background them there's no need to wait. And as Nate said, just add all of them to a script and execute that from cron.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer thanks to Nate Eldredge, just put it all together in-case useful to anyone. Also, thanks to Tink.

crontab -e #then enter code in the editor #Note $USER may need to be changed  to your name.

```
* 22 * * * mkdir -p /home/$USER/me/arnor/hobbits/ ; cp -r -p /home/$USER/me/arnor/hobbits/ /home/$USER/me/shire/ ; mv /home/$USER/me/arnor/hobbits/ /home/$USER/me/buckland/ ; gunzip -r /home/$USER/me/buckland/hobbits ; mv /home/$USER/me/buckland/hobbits /home/$USER/me/gondor/
```